# Set activity "Type" upon a quick Action on Case

Tags: email, activities, publisher-action, casefeed

On Case Feed Layout, there are couple of QuickActions - such as "Email", Log-a-call, Log an Activity.

[image: QuickActions]

When i send an email (or log a call, or log an activity) using these actions, i can see it reflects in "Activity History" of the case. But the field "Type" of those activities is not set. Is there a way for me to set it (see the pic below)?
[image: No "Type" on activity history]

If an email was sent, i want corresponding activity history to have Type=Email. If a call was logged, i want its corresponding activity history to have Type=Call.

Would it be possible to do it if i create my own custom Action?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a field update in workflow to set the type field based on the record types or something which suits you in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The acitivities are automatically logged in history (standard feature)

To achieve what you want -

- You will have to create an apex trigger on Task "event - before
  insert".
- You will have to check for for subject.
- If subject starts with 'Email' then assign 'Email' to Type field.
- If subject starts with 'Call' then assign 'Call' to Type field.

Comment: Yes i thought about using trigger or workflow (both solutions suggested here), but i need to find a better identifier. Subject line can change. Infact, subject line WILL change with each case. Agent can choose any subject he wants to put in there. 

Is there a better identifier? Any way i can do this via custom actions (I am very new to salesforce)?